# Using dynamic parameters for binding ElementName in styles. Reusing styles

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a question.
I have created a style in WPF designer (XML) for TextBlocks. After IsMouseOver event is fired on any of two image controls, my textBlocks changes its positions. This style is used for some textBlocks.

```
<Style x:Key="movingTextBlocksStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=image1, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" From="0" To="-125"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=image2, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" From="0" To="-125"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This style will be used as:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Style="{StaticResource movingTextBlocksStyle}"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Style="{StaticResource movingTextBlocksStyle}"/>
```

My problem is that I want to reuse this style for another textBlocks: textBlock3 and textBlock4 where "Binding ElementName" differs, for example image3 and image4.
I have thought that if there was any possibility to reuse this style with some type of dynamic parameter or argument, it would be great.
I searched for any solution only as xml-code without any C# (I am using C# with WPF) or converter implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you create a custom control that will have Image and TextBlock child's??

Comment: Because they are different controls, and the location of them on the form is very variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's pure XAML solution:

Collect all controls on which the text block depends in an array and set it as data context:

```
<Image x:Name="image1"/>
<Image x:Name="image2"/>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource movingTextBlocksStyle}">
    <TextBlock.DataContext>
        <x:Array Type="system:Object">
            <x:Reference>image1</x:Reference>
            <x:Reference>image2</x:Reference>
        </x:Array>
    </TextBlock.DataContext>
</TextBlock>
```

You'll need to remember to change all bindings on the `TextBlock` properties accordingly, because data context is no longer inherited. Then in the style definition bind using corresponding array indices:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding [0].IsMouseOver}" Value="True">...</DataTrigger>
...
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding [1].IsMouseOver}" Value="True">...</DataTrigger>
```

The `system:` prefix namespace is `clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib`.

Comment: Wow. Moment. I need 10 minutes more for consideration

Comment: @Gargoyle To address your question directly - no, there is no way to dynamically set `BindingExtension.ElementName` property in XAML, so there is no way to use "some type of dynamic parameter or argument", let alone in a style referenced via `StaticResourceExtension`. And writing a converter would require C# code.

Answer (score 0):

You could define attached properties which would hold the controls on which the `TextBox` depends, like so (I'll use only one property to keep it brief):

```
static class Helper
{
    public static object GetImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(ImageProperty);
    }
    public static void SetImage(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Image",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(Helper),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Then, in the data trigger, bind using the attached property:

```
...
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(local:Helper.Image).IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
...
```

Lastly, set the property value to be the control on which the `TextBlock` depends:

```
<Image x:Name="image1"/>
...
<TextBlock local:Helper.Image="{Binding ElementName=image1}"
           Style="{StaticResource movingTextBlocksStyle}"/>
```

This solution is not pure XAML - it requires a little bit of code-behind to define the attached properties, but I doubt there's an elegant way to completely avoid it.

Comment: Thanks, but as I already said, I would like to avoid C# parts